# Python: multiple string test for standard Uk reg, why not working?

Tags: python

The following is a section that has been separated from the main program to just test the snippet if it works. The "yes" output was for testing each string method required to see where errors arises. This does not seem to work and I cant figure out why as I have put all tests for standard UK reg, checking characters as they appear from an input.

As you can see im a very low level (new to python) programmer, please consider that as you are providing solutions. Many thanks

```
def main():
    reg_number=input("What is your reg number?: ")
    correct_length = False
    first_two_char_capital = False
    next_two_char_digits= False
    next_char_space = False
    last_three_char_capital= False

    first_two_char_capital =reg_number[0:2]
    print(first_two_char_capital)
    next_two_char_digits=reg_number[2:4]
    print (next_two_char_digits)
    next_char_space=reg_number[4:5]
    print(next_char_space)
    last_three_char_capital=reg_number[5:8]
    print (last_three_char_capital)

    if len (reg_number) >= 8:
           correct_length = True
           print("yes1")

           for ch in reg_number:
               if first_two_char_capital.isupper():
                   first_two_char_capital = True
                   print("yes2")
               if next_two_char_digits.isdigit():
                   next_two_char_digits = True
                   print("yes3")
               if next_char_space.isspace():
                   next_char_space = True
                   print("yes4")
               if last_three_char_capital.isupper():
                   last_three_char_capital = True
                   print("yes5")
           if correct_length and first_two_char_capital and next_two_char_digits and next_char_space and last_three_char_capital:
               is_valid = False
               print(reg_number, "is a non-standard_registration")
           else:
               is_valid = True

               print(reg_number, "is a standard registration")
               return is_valid

main()
```

Answer (score 3):

It's much easier to just use a regular expression here, eg:

```
import re

if re.match('[A-Z]{2}\d{2} [A-Z]{3}$', input('What is your regnumber:')):
    print('yeah it matches...')
```

Comment: Can I have another solution that uses string slicing,

Comment: StackOverflow is a forum for professionals and enthusiastic amateurs, not a forum for asking to write N silliest programs possible to match a given problem.